# Sonata throwing RuntimeException on add pages

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

Sonata is throwing the following exception when trying to add elements using the CRUDController and Doctrine:

```
You are using a closure with the `InlineConstraint`, this constraint cannot be serialized. You need to re-attach the `InlineConstraint` on each request. Once done, you can set the `serializingWarning` option to `true` to avoid this message.
```

Any idea where and how to deactivate this and what could be the cause of this Exception? I don't see anything like this in the docs as well.

It is thrown here:

```
in vendor/sonata-project/core-bundle/Validator/Constraints/InlineConstraint.php at line 34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved when using version dev-master in the composer.json:

```
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master"
```

This pulls the newest version 2.3.6 of SonataCore which includes the lastest changes by rande: 
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/3179